# C# Domain change broke custom GetUserEmail method

Tags: c#, asp.net

The 'Users' on the network were moved to another domain recently. This caused a local method that gets the user's email address to break for a few of our web applications. This problem would likely fix itself after the web server is moved to the same domain, but would request help in fixing the code to allow this method to work in this split domain network (ex. Domain1.ad.com, Domain2.ad.com).

```
// Method below gets users email address.
public static string GetUserEmailAddress()
{
    // Grab users network name.  It will be in the form domain\username.
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
    string NetworkID = p.Identity.Name;
    // Remove the domain.
    string[] networkIDparts = NetworkID.Split('\\');
    string UserID = networkIDparts[1];

    DirectorySearcher objsearch = new DirectorySearcher(); 
    objsearch.Filter = "(& (cn="+ UserID.Trim() + ")(objectClass=user))";
    objsearch.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
    objsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail"); 
    objsearch.PropertyNamesOnly = true ;
    objsearch.Sort.Direction = System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending;
    SearchResultCollection colresults = objsearch.FindAll() ; 
    ArrayList arrGal = new ArrayList(); 

    foreach(SearchResult objresult in colresults)
    {
        arrGal.Add(objresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value);
    } 

    objsearch.Dispose();
    String[] myArray = (String[]) arrGal.ToArray(typeof(string));

    if (myArray.Length == 0)
    { return "NoAddressAssigned@domain2.ad.com";}
    else
    { return myArray[0] ;}
}
```

I'm also open to any ideas that would improve the functionality of this method.

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior? (Exception, return of the default value)

Comment: The method currently returns NoAddressAssigned@domain.ad.com, because it is not looking at the correct domain.